# How to access properties of a .m file into another .m file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, objective-c-category, xctest

I have class ABCD.m, as below

```
**ABCD.m**
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *button;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *string;
- (void) firstMethod;
- (void) setTheButtonWithBool:(BOOL)var1 withString:(NSString *)var2;

-(void) firstMethod {
 // Alloc init button
 self.button.enabled = NO;
}

- (void) setTheButtonWithBool:(BOOL)var1 withString:(NSString *)var2  {
  self.button.enabled = var1;
  self.string = var2;
}
```

There is another class Test.m(subclass of XCTestCase) to write the unit test cases for ABCD.m

```
**Test.m** //Sub-class of XCTestCase

//Extension
@interface ABCD.m () 
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *button;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *string;
 - (void) firstMethod;
 - (void) setTheButtonWithBool:(BOOL)var1 withString:(NSString *)var2;
@end


@interace Test : XCTestCase

- (void)testSomeMethod {
 ABCD *abcd = [ABCD alloc] init];  
 BOOL *var1 = YES; 
 NSString *var2 = @"StackOverFlow";
 [abcd firstMethod]; 
 [abcd setTheButtonWithBool:var1 withString:var2];
 nslog(@"Result1 :%hhd", self.abcd.button.isEnabled);             -----
 nslog(@"Result2: %@", self.abcd.string);                         -----
 // Assert statement
```

}

OUTPUT:

Result 1: NO

Result 2: StackOverFlow

When i set the property 'string' it is getting set to 'StackOverFlow'. But for UIButton property 'button' it is not getting set to 'NO'.
Why cant I set 'enabled' property of UIButton where as i can set the NSString of ABCD.m from the Test.m class

Comment: first can u please check whether the button object is initialized.
Because there is no code available in ur sample for initializing the button.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple. You never set the `button` property on your `ABCD` instance. There is no code that creates a `UIButton` and assigns it to the `button` property.

A call like `self.button.enabled = NO` is translated to `[[self button] setEnabled:NO]`. Since you haven't set `button`, the call to `[self button]` returns `nil`. So now you call `setEnabled:` on a `nil` object which is basically a no-op.

Add code to create a button and set the `button` property and the rest of the code will work properly.